# template does not exist error in django?

Tags: django

it renders the form correctly

```
<div >
<form method="post" action="{% url 'parts:stock_add_view'%}">
    {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

but while rendering

```
<div >
<form method="post" action="{% url 'parts:stock_add_view'%}">
    {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.form_element }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

but while rendering the single form field on submitting it shows template does not exist. I am using UpdateView to render the form

```
class stock_add_view(CreateView):
    model = part_stock
    fields = ['part_id','entry_date','supplier','amount','remaining']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('parts:part_list')
```

in part_view_detail I am passing the form that is to be rendered in the  part_detail_view

```
class part_detail_view(DetailView):
    model = part_list
    context_object_name = 'part_detail'
    template_name = 'part_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(part_detail_view, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['my_list'] = populate_nav_bar()
        context['form'] = part_stock_form()
        return context
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error message: it would be interesting which template it cannot find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanna hide some form fields in template. This may be useful for you.

You can check the documentation for more information;

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```